# Getting only the last entry on counting

Tags: c#

I'm only getting the last entry of the counting typed like this

```
public string ZodziuSkaiciavimas()
    {

        foreach (var sentence in Sakiniai.TrimEnd('.').Split('.'))
        {
            Rezultatas=(eilute.ToString() + " sakinyje zodziu:" + (sentence.Trim().Split(' ').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split('-').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split(';').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split(':').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split(',').Count() - 4));
            eilute++;
        }  
        return Rezultatas;
```

And I need to get the answer with a return type.
If I type code like this than i get what i want,but no returns.

```
public string ZodziuSkaiciavimas()
    {

        foreach (var sentence in Sakiniai.TrimEnd('.').Split('.'))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(eilute.ToString() + " sakinyje zodziu:" + (sentence.Trim().Split(' ').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split('-').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split(';').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split(':').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split(',').Count() - 4));
            eilute++;
        }  
        return Rezultatas;
    }
```

Comment: It is very inefficient to repeat `sentence.Trim().Split(':').Count()` multiple times. [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method supports multiple separators. How about something like this: `string words = sentence.Trim().Split(new char[]{' ', '-', ';', ':', ','});` and then `Console.WriteLine(eilute.ToString() + " sakinyje zodziu: " + (words.Length - 4).ToString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why arent you appending your results as below

```
Rezultatas +=(eilute.ToString() + " sakinyje zodziu:" + (sentence.Trim().Split(' ').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split('-').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split(';').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split(':').Count() + sentence.Trim().Split(',').Count() - 4)) + "\n";
```

Comment: Perhaps OP follows [a good advise from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182272(v=vs.80).aspx), telling him not to concatenate strings in a loop.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight :)..from the question felt thats wats missing..thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to return multiple numbers from your method, but `Rezultatas` is a single `string`. You can fix it by changing the return type to `List<int>`, and returning a list:

```
public List<int> ZodziuSkaiciavimas() {
    var Rezultatas = new List<int>()
    foreach (var sentence in Sakiniai.TrimEnd('.').Split('.')) {
        var res = sentence.Trim().Split(' ', '-', ';', ':', ',').Length;
        Rezultatas.Add(res);
    }  
    return Rezultatas;
}
```

When the callers decide to print the `Rezultatas` they gets back from your method, they could decide what character to put between the numbers (say, a comma `','`) and print it like this:

```
var numbers = ZodziuSkaiciavimas();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers));
```